# Can I get a JSON object with name value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a Covid-19 tracker App by ReactJS.
I want to get data that only an object (a specific province value) from JSON API with ProvinceChange event.

**Problem :**

I can't get data that is only an object (a specific province value).

**what I tried :**

I tried a method filter using `province.name` but is not work, as I get

[image]

**Sample JSON API :**

```
[
{
    "txn_date": "2022-03-07",
    "province": "กระบี่",
    "new_case": 112,
    "total_case": 18101,
    "new_case_excludeabroad": 112,
    "total_case_excludeabroad": 17838,
    "new_death": 2,
    "total_death": 93,
    "update_date": "2022-03-07 07:20:43"
},
{
    "txn_date": "2022-03-07",
    "province": "กรุงเทพมหานคร",
    "new_case": 2815,
    "total_case": 590810,
    "new_case_excludeabroad": 2809,
    "total_case_excludeabroad": 587121,
    "new_death": 7,
    "total_death": 7126,
    "update_date": "2022-03-07 07:20:43"
},
{
    "txn_date": "2022-03-07",
    "province": "กาญจนบุรี",
    "new_case": 176,
    "total_case": 33734,
    "new_case_excludeabroad": 176,
    "total_case_excludeabroad": 33684,
    "new_death": 2,
    "total_death": 214,
    "update_date": "2022-03-07 07:20:43"
},
{
    "txn_date": "2022-03-07",
    "province": "กาฬสินธุ์",
    "new_case": 214,
    "total_case": 18163,
    "new_case_excludeabroad": 214,
    "total_case_excludeabroad": 18159,
    "new_death": 0,
    "total_death": 97,
    "update_date": "2022-03-07 07:20:43"
},]
```

**This is my code :**

```js
const App = ()=>{
  const [provinces, setProvinces] = useState([]);
  const [province, setProvince] = useState("thailand");
  const [provinceInfo, setProvinceInfo] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
   
   const getProvincesData = async  () => {
     fetch("https://covid19.ddc.moph.go.th/api/Cases/today-cases-by-provinces")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const provinces = data.map((province) => ({
          name: province.province,
        }));
        setProvinces(provinces);
      });
   };
  
    getProvincesData();
  }, []); 

  const onProvinceChange = async (event) =>{
    const provinceCode = event.target.value;
    //setProvince(provinceCode);

    const url = 
      provinceCode === "thailand"
       ? "https://covid19.ddc.moph.go.th/api/Cases/today-cases-all"
       : 'https://covid19.ddc.moph.go.th/api/Cases/today-cases-by-provinces' ;

    await fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const provinceInfo = data.filter((data) => {
          return data.name === '{province.name}'
        })
        setProvince(provinceCode);
      // All of the data from the province response
        setProvinceInfo(data);
        });
    
    };
  
  console.log(provinceInfo);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className='app__left'>
        <div className="app__header">
          <h1>COVID-19 TRACKER in Thailand</h1>
          <FormControl>
            <Select variant="outlined" onChange={onProvinceChange} value={province}>
              <MenuItem value="thailand">ประเทศไทย</MenuItem>
              {provinces.map((province) => (
                <MenuItem value={province.name}>{province.name}</MenuItem>     // Loop through all the province and show drop down list of the option 
              ))}

            </Select>
          </FormControl>
       </div>
    </div>
  
  );
}
```

Comment: what does this mean `data.name === '{province.name}'` can you share the info like what are the keys to be matched in the array of objects from response against what in the dropdown

Comment: your filtered `provinceInfo` variable is never used. should it maybe `setProvinceInfo(provinceInfo)`?

Comment: Ah, you're correct. it should be setProvinceInfo(provinceInfo). thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, it looks like you're trying to set `provinceInfo` to the single province you're searching for by `provinceCode.` There are two changes to make if that's the case:

1. `'{province.name}'`is a string. I think you need to change that to `provinceCode` which is a variable reference set to the province you want.
2. It looks like you're trying to set `provinceInfo` to an object. `.filer()` will return an array with only items matching, so you probably want [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead, which returns just one.

So you can change:

```
const provinceInfo = data.filter((data) => {
  return data.name === '{province.name}'
})
```

To...

```
const provinceInfo = data.find((province) =>  province.name === provinceCode)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to set provinceInfo to an object and return just one item matching. I can now solve this problem with  .find() , thank you for your suggestion.